# Equivalent definitions of doubly transitive group actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G act transitively on a set X and let $H_x$ denote the subgroup of G which consists of all elements of G that stabilizes $x \in X$. Consider the following :

(a) $H_x$ acts transitively on $X$\ {$x$}.

(b) $G=$$H_x$ $U $ $H_x gH_x$, where $g \in G$ such that $g$ is not in $H_x$.

Assuming either (a) or (b), we can show that G acts doubly transitively.

(Given (b) 
we see that $Gx=$$H_xx$ $U $ $H_x gH_xx$  $\implies$ $X$= {$x$} $U $ $H_x gx$ $\implies$ $H_x gx$ contains $X$\ {$x$}. Therefore $H_x$ acts transitively on $X$\ {$x$}. Hence (a).)

Now I want to show (a) without using (b) i.e given that G acts doubly transitively if, given $x,x',y,y' \in X$ and $x\neq x'$ and $y \neq y'$, there exists an element $g \in G$ with $(g(x),g(x')) = (y,y')$. I want to show that $H_x$ acts transitively on $X$\ {$x$} (without invoking (b) in between). I tried and after many steps, finally arrived at this:

To show: $g_1$$H_{x_1}$ $intersection$ $H_x$ is not empty if $g_1 \notin H_x$ and $x_1\neq x$

Comment: Just pick a $g$ such that $g(x) = x$ and $g(y) = y'$ where you have picked $y$ and $y'$ in $X\setminus\{x\}$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That is the problem. As I mentioned at the end, the original problem reduced to being able to pick an element which will fix x but move $x_1$ to anywhere else in $X$.

Comment: The element I said to pick exists directly due to the definition of doubly transitive.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah! I see. Thanks.